# How to thank somebody for editing his answer or comment and adding value to it?

Tags: discussion

This is not really about Blender, but this site (sorry that I couldn't find a tag for it, and because it is required, and I cant add a tag yet, had to use the nearest possible). The site asks to avoid comments like "thanks" and rightfully, to avoid cluttering text with extras that are not useful to the others. But my friend @Georgious included a file I requested by editing his old answer to my question. I am asked to avoid "thanks", but I don't feel good just leaving it like this! So there must be a way to say our thanks without cluttiring the text with too much comments uninteresting for other readers. How :) ?

Answer (score 9):

I feel like I'm entitled to answer this question since it looks like I'm the person you're looking to thank :).

You don't need to explicitely thank back people that helped you. The only gratification system on this site is the upvote (or downvote) system. Additionally if you asked the question and the answer correctly solved it, you can mark it as answered.

Of course it's always nice to try and add some cordiality in places where it makes sense, I think we can all benefit from it in this day and age.

I can talk only for myself, of course, but I assume most people are like me and they participate on this site for a number of reasons :

- To improve their blender skills
- To improve their explanation and teaching skills
- To get a dopamine rush when they get internet points for participating
- To engage in a stoical yet really respectful and open-minded community
- To give back what they learnt along the way

A thank you in the comments, while frowned upon since it's against the guidelines, won't get you insta-banned for life.

Personally, the simple knowledge that I helped at least one person along the wonderful journey that I am also a part of is well enough. But oh man do I crave the green popup dopamine rush..!

Comment: "*To get a dopamine rush when they get internet points for participating*" I loved that :D. Thanking in the comments is fine as far as I'm concerned, the rules advise against it, but but it can be removed in the long term and I supposed it is a harmless way to add a little social warmth to a site that is often accused of being cold and hostile.

Answer (score 1):

You can tap on

[image]

under your question. After a while (i think 2 days or so) you can then give the bounty to his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest putting an icon next to answers and comments to enable "thanks" without cluttering useful text. next to the icon a number representing the number this icon was clicked.
I would like to didicate this suggestion to @Georgious & @moonboots :)

Comment: You can already do that using the up and down arrows beside the answer and the person asking the question can also accept the answer which puts a green tick icon beside the answer. Both of these also add reputation 'points' to the person answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We don't want to clutter up the site with things such as thanks, etc.. But I am Latin American, and it really, really burns me. I find myself to be unable to behave with such efficiency. It is just rude, in my view, to be so cold and insulting. Cheers.

Comment: By the way, I posted the above as a question or answer because I was not allowed to post a comment. Tks