# Thanks And Hi's

Tags: discussion

I was going through some old files and found this:  https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/. I think that is from 2018 or 19. From my short and very good time here at StackExchange, I still find "don't use thanks" and the like. Being Latin American, this is quite disconcerting. When I travel to the U.S., I sometimes go into culture shock, such efficiency. In your more rural areas folks tend to be more courteous. Please don't misunderstand, I think your people are great. Thank for your attention. Cheers!

Comment: Hi for questions about this site and how it works please use meta https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: Tks Duarte. I hope I'm the only one who is lost around here.

Comment: @Roberto being a rural folk myself, I have to agree :)

Comment: @ Allen Simpson I found at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, the comment: Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".  I say in the name of "rural folk" and others: Tar and Feather people who say such things. Smile

Comment: also this one https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2811/how-to-thank-somebody-for-editing-his-answer-or-comment-and-adding-value-to-it